# I have installed Ubuntu in my hard disk but it only runs with the pendrive inserted

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I am using ubuntu 19.04 version. 
My Linux is not working when I remove the bootable pendrive.
I have it installed on my hard disk. 
I did install Ubuntu to the hard drive from the USB flash drive, and then i showing that "no bootable device" the install program to reboot. When i remove the USB flash drive then it showing that "no bootable device".

Comment: _Vijay_, 1) did you install Ubuntu to the hard drive from the USB flash drive, and 2) then tell the install program to reboot? If so, 3) did you remove the USB flash drive when it told you to? 4) Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Please click [edit] to add the answers to 1-4 to your question. Please do not click Add Comment, please use [edit] instead. Editing tips are at https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code .

Comment: Is there any chance that you installed the boot loader on the flash drive by mistake?